# Watermelon Sync With Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm wanting to use watermelon sync with Firestore but I'm not getting it. I do not even know where to begin with. I'm not using API. I want to do it only in React Native. I want to sync my app offline and online. Can someone help me??
Im using React Native to do That...

```
import { synchronize } from '@nozbe/watermelondb/sync'

async function mySync() {
  await synchronize({
    database,
    pullChanges: async ({ lastPulledAt, schemaVersion, migration }) => {
      const urlParams = `last_pulled_at=${lastPulledAt}&schema_version=${schemaVersion}&migration=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(migration))}`
      const response = await fetch(`https://my.backend/sync?${urlParams}`)
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(await response.text())
      }

      const { changes, timestamp } = await response.json()
      return { changes, timestamp }
    },
    pushChanges: async ({ changes, lastPulledAt }) => {
      const response = await fetch(`https://my.backend/sync?last_pulled_at=${lastPulledAt}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(changes)
      })
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(await response.text())
      }
    },
    migrationsEnabledAtVersion: 1,
  })
}
```

the example above is the code shown on the Watermelon website.  But I want to do it without using API!  Only with React Native and Firestore/firebase.  How could I do this in react Native, and whenever there is any change in the application it automatically saves it in the database when the user is connected to the internet?  My app is Offline Frist

Answer (score 1):

There are some packages that helps with syncing react native to firebase and you won't need to build your own backend server and apis. To quote from the watermelondb docs.

> [MelonFire](https://github.com/fivecar/melon-fire), a React Native library to sync your database to Firestore. MelonFire overcomes common bugs in implementations (e.g. timestamp jitter, multiple writers, Firestore's 500-write transaction limit, retries) to guarantee database consistency.

> [Firemelon](https://github.com/AliAllaf/firemelon), an alternative implementation to sync your database to Firestore. It relies on changes being smaller than Firestore's 500-write transaction limit, and doesn't handle server timestamp intricacies, but supports ignoring certain tables when backing up.

Hope this helps.